# Android ListView with RadioButton/CheckBox in singleChoice mode and a custom row layout

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, listviewitem

I have a ListView, which is in singleChoice mode. All I want is to display a RadioButton to the side, that when clicked highlights to say it is selected, and when a different one is clicked that one hides and the new one becomes selected.

I looked in Mark's book, Chapter 8, "Getting Fancy With Lists" and his RateList example
But it doesn't solve my problem.
Please help me .

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT**

Worth mentioning is that I had a custom layout on my list items: There is an icon, a title, a description and then the checkbox or radio button (depending on if it's a single or multiple choice list). My example solution is, hence described by no less than three different parts:

1. The custom listitem
2. The sweet tender love: the CheckableLinearLayout implementation
3. An example `ListView` configuration
  And a bonus:
4. Example `Adapter::getView()` implementation.

So let's get to the magic then, shall we?

*listitem.xml*

```
<com.dbm.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/myIcon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/myTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/myDescr" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/text1" />

</com.dbm.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

*CheckableLinearLayout.java*

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

    private CheckedTextView mCheckedTextView;
    private final Drawable mCheckDrawable;
    private final Drawable mRadioDrawable;
    private boolean mIsChecked;


       /**
        * Constructor.
        *
        * @param context The context to operate in.
        * @param attrs The attributes defined in XML for this element.
        */
    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = null;

        // Cache the check box drawable.
        typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple});

        if ((typedArray != null) && (typedArray.length() > 0)) {
            mCheckDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
        }
        else {
            // Fallback if the target theme doesn't define a check box drawable.
            // Perhaps an application specific drawable should be used instead of null.
            mCheckDrawable = null;
        }

        // Careful with resources like this, we don't need any memory leaks.
        typedArray.recycle();

        // Cache the radio button drawable.
        typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle});

        if ((typedArray != null) && (typedArray.length() > 0)) {
            mRadioDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
        }
        else {
            // Fallback if the target theme doesn't define a radio button drawable.
            // Perhaps an application specific drawable should be used instead of null
            mRadioDrawable = null;
        }

        // Careful with resources like this, we don't need any memory leaks.
        typedArray.recycle();

        mIsChecked = false;
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mIsChecked;
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View#onAttachedToWindow()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        // Check if there is a valid GUI element that can visualize the current check-state.
        if (mCheckedTextView != null) {
            ViewParent p = getParent();

            // Check if the parent of this list item is a ListView
            if (p instanceof ListView) {
                int choiceMode = ((ListView) p).getChoiceMode();

                // Decide which check-state notation to visualize (check box, radio button or none).
                switch (choiceMode) {
                    case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE:
                        mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(mCheckDrawable);
                        break;

                    case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE:
                        mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(mRadioDrawable);
                        break;

                    default:
                        mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View#onFinishInflate()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        mCheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mIsChecked = checked;

        if (mCheckedTextView != null) {
            mCheckedTextView.setChecked(mIsChecked);
        }
    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mIsChecked);
    }

}
```

*exampleListView.xml*

NOTE! that you will automatically get check boxes if you set the `android:choiceMode` attribute to `"multipleChoice"` and radio buttons if you set it to `"singleChoice"`, provided you use the above implementation.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:id="@+id/myList" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Bonus: *MyCustomAdapter::getView()*

This one relies on a Cursor. You will, of course, implement it as you see fit for your needs.

```
private final class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView iconView;
    public TextView titleView;
    public TextView descriptionView;
}


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    // Only do something if the requested position exists within the Cursor.
    if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            // Create and initialize a new view if not created already for this position.
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

            // Don't "find view by id" each and every time, but rather save a reference
            // to them and associate the references with the list item itself by storing 
            // them in the list items "tag" attribute. When the view is re-used later on, 
            // you already have a reference to its views and don't need to find them 
            // again, which is a time-consuming operation.
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
            viewHolder.titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
            viewHolder.descriptionView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myDescr);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            // Get the references to the views for this, already existing list item.
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        // Create a bitmap from the byte array in the database.
        byte[] buffer = mCursor.getBlob(mIconColumnIndex);
        Bitmap icon = null;

        // Try to decode the byte array if it exists.
        if (buffer != null) {
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }

        // Update the views with new data.
        viewHolder.iconView.setImageBitmap(icon);

        String title = mCursor.getString(mTitleColumnIndex);
        viewHolder.titleView.setText(title);

        String description = mCursor.getString(mDescriptionColumnIndex);
        viewHolder.descriptionView.setText(description);
    }

    // Return a view showing the correct data for the item at 'position'.
    return view;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I can suggest this link:

http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/

I myself have had great pleasure in it when I was in your exact position :-) If anything still is unclear, please feel free to specify your question and I will gladly try to help or assist with further code examples (just as mention earlier: I've been in your position just a few days ago).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I read http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/ link ,but now I it doesn't open in my browser.But I have some difficulties to understand it and couldn't solve my problem,If you can ,please write here more detail

Comment: Note:that link doesn't open in my browser.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear dbm I wait to your answer.                                      Please help.

Comment: Patiens my dear friend! I have a full time job, a wife and two children which all have higher prio than this community, and besides that I suspect we sit in vastly different time zones :-) I have, however, modified my answer above. Please let me know if something is unclear :-)

Comment: i read your code above and am confused. where do you create your raidobuttons and where is your radio group object?

Comment: The `com.dbm.CheckableLinearLayout` (xml) holds a `CheckedTextView` element which corresponds to a radio button (or a check box). The big picture is the following: 1) There is a `ListView` with a `android:choiceMode` attribute. 2) The adapter for the list inflates `listview.xml` items (which hold a `com.dbm.CheckableLinearLayout` root layout element). 3) The Java implementation (`CheckableLinearLayout.java`) sets the correct style attribute to the `CheckedTextView` element depending on the `android:choiceMode` attribute of the list. 4) The rest is automagically managed by Android.

Comment: @dbm I have checkbox and edittext in the custom listview ,can u please tell me how to hide the black dot of checkedtextview

Comment: Thank you very much @dbm but there is a problem with my list view, only in the first and last row, the radiobutton (or checkbox) are not apearing so they are not select-able. Last question is this: where can i get the user choice when i'm leaving the fragment or activity of the listview? in the CustomCheckable layout or in my adapter??

Answer (score 3):

I used [dbm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842390/366904) and it worked fine for me except one thing:

You should initiate `CheckedTextView` in `onAttachedToWindow()` method, not in `onFinishInflate().` This is because `onAttachedToWindow()` called *before* `onFinishInflate()` and using the solution above you will never see any drawable in `CheckedTextView`—it is null when `onAttachedToWindow()` called.

Comment: Thanks Darkmine, I changed the initialization but again I have the problem of not showing the option button on the first and the last row! The click listener, ... everything is working, except showing those radio buttons in those 2 rows. Can you suggest any solution?