# How to display two lines of text per choice for a Single Choice List in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[This is a great tutorial on how to get a Single Choice List in Android](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-create-single-choice-list) to work, but I need one more thing: I want two lines of text instead of one. So, it would look like this:

```
|-----------------------------|
| FIRST LINE OF TEXT      (o) | <- this is a "RadioButton". Ideally, 
| second line of text         |    it would be centered vertically.
|-----------------------------|
```

[This SO question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346406/android-how-to-make-alertdialog-with-2-text-lines-and-radiobutton-single-choice), but I'm an Android newb, so it's a little over my head. Can anyone break it down for me so that I can use it in the context of the tutorial I linked above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the custom layout for this.

for display list as it like

this is your layout file

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/mylistview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is your custom list view style

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <LinearLayout
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
              <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/text1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Text view 1"/>
              <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/text2"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Text view 2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radiobtn" 
        android:width="wrap_content" android:height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now you have to implement any adapter like BaseAdapter,ArrayAdapter etc.

and use this custom list view in that

like this way

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

        private ArrayList<Model> items;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Model> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null); // here you have to implement custom_list.xml file
                }
                Model m = items.get(position);
                if (m != null) {
                        TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                        TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radiobtn);
                        text1.setText(m.text1);
                        text1.setText(m.text2);
                        rb.setChecked(m.isChecked);
                }
                return v;
        }
}
```

here is your Model class for your list item

```
private class Model{
    String text1;
    String text2;
    boolean isChecked;
}
```

Comment: So for this call `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,colors);`, I would instead do: `CustomAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,colors);`? Is it correct to still use the simple_list_item_single_choice layout here?

Comment: no need to use simple_list_item_single_choice layout when you using your custom layout

Comment: I noticed that you aren't using a RadioGroup. How does the logic work in this case?

Comment: check into the getView method that one them are checked or not if checked than unchecked that radio button. Now if you using radiogroup then also it will be set into one row of list object. This is the group of object which we set into the row of list

Comment: Back in the code, how do I use this custom adapter to bind a SQLite database cursor to the layout? I'm currently using a SimpleCursorAdapter...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code of [simple_list_item_single_choice.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_single_choice.xml?av=f), we can figure out how to make a custom widget that implements [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html), like this:

File `simple_list_item_2_single_choice.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customwidgets.CheckedLinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" />
 </customwidgets.CheckedLinearLayout>
```

That is, we add as many `TextView`s as we need and make last one to be a `CheckedTextView`.

Then, in our custom `CheckedLinearLayout` we find which one is the `Checkable` child of the layout and dispatch each method of `Checkable` we implement to that child, like this:

File `CheckedLinearLayout.java`

```
package customwidgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Useful class inside a ListView that needs to have checkable items,
 * such as radio buttons (single_choice) or check boxes (multiple_choice).
 */
public class CheckedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

    private Checkable checkedView;

    public CheckedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checkedView == null ? false : checkedView.isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (checkedView != null) checkedView.setChecked(checked);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (checkedView != null) checkedView.toggle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof Checkable) {
                checkedView = (Checkable) view;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in the desired xml file of the layout, we set the `ListView` to be single choiced:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
</ListView>
```