# Android: Two-line list view with radio buttons, can’t select items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xml-layout

I would like to display a list of paired Bluetooth devices and let the user select one. I’m trying to create a two-line list view (one line for the friendly device name, the other for the MAC address) with radio buttons.

To this end I have copied [simple_list_item_2_single_choice.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2_single_choice.xml) into my project and create my list view with the following code:

```
listView = new ListView(activity);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(activity,
    R.layout.simple_list_item_2_single_choice, android.R.id.text1) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

        text1.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        text2.setText(getItem(position).getAddress());
        return view;
    }
};
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// addAll() is not supported on APIs below 11
for (BluetoothDevice device : devices)
    listViewAdapter.add(device);
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

This displays the list the way I want it, but I can’t select any items (the radio button stays empty when I tap an item). What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how this worked in AOSP (they might use non-standard logic for the layout), but with a standard list view the key is that **the root item of the View must implement the Checkable interface**.

So, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5353634/2703209), I did the following:

- Created a CheckableLayout, derived from LinearLayout, otherwise just as described in the answer
- Changed the top-level view in my copy of simple_list_item_2_single_choice.xml to CheckableLayout (this requires a fully qualified class name).

With these changes it works as intended. I can check items by tapping them, and the items will behave like a group of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you need to know, but a radio button can be set checked with this:

```
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```

And if you need to set radiobutton checked when the view is clicked, i think you can do in your getView something like (where "radio" is your radioId set in your layout):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    RadioButton rbutton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rbutton.setChecked(true);
        }
    });

    text1.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    text2.setText(getItem(position).getAddress());
    return view;
}
```

Let me know if works.