# android listview with checkboxes , without list activity

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Without using listactivity, in a simple activity how can I have checkbox at the left followed by the text in the right for every row of a listview. If I tap on any row , the check box should be selected.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html check this link..

Comment: It extends a list activity, which is not my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Check out this tutorial - it will give you an idea how to implement custom listview item layouts.
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/</s>

To make the checkbox change state when any part of the whole item is clicked, add an OnClickListener to your item's layout root element (convertView) and switch the checkbox state there.

**PS** Don't mind the ListActivity stuff there. It will work either way. What matters is the custom Adapter and it's getView() method that inflates custom layouts of your items.

**UPD** Here's a more adequate way to accomplish what you want: your items should implement Checkable and then you can use ListViews singleChoice or multipleChoice mode with it. Here's an answered question about that, although, the answer seems to miss the actual part about the checkbox. But I bet you can figure it out, what matters is the idea:

[Android ListView with RadioButton/CheckBox in singleChoice mode and a custom row layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842349/android-listview-with-radiobutton-checkbox-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row)

Comment: I tried the same but when I inflate the rows of listview without checkbox, the setOnItemClickListener is working. But when I added check box to the row,  the setOnItemClickListener of listview is not getting called.

Comment: You can use an OnClickListener for root view of your row and the checkbox. That way, you click on checkbox - it receives the event. You click on anything else in that row - the row's root view receives the event. They both can do the same thing - call toggle() on checkbox.

Comment: Although, there seems to be more adequate solution to what you're trying to accomplish. I've added a link to the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just get reference from xml, using:

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Set adapter on your activity

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

setChoice Mode to single choice mode or multiple choice mode

```
listVIew.setChoiceMode(ListView.Choice_Mode_Mutlitple);
```

now you can select and deselect checkboxes in listview.

Comment: But this gives check box on to the right where as I need it on left

Comment: then you can create your custom one