# Error Inflating View And Class Not Found Exception For ListView With RadioButtons

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, radio-button, android-checkbox

I am developing an application where i need to have a listview with radiobuttons with values obtained from an array that is populated dynamically.

I had used the example found [here in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842349/android-listview-with-radiobutton-checkbox-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row) to get things off the ground:

I also adapted it to meet my needs based on my requirements and using code i am comfortable with.

My xml file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/myList" />
```

xml file2:

```
<com.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/myTitle"
         android:textColor="#000"
         />


</LinearLayout>

<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" />
```

my main activity:

```
            public class ListDemo  extends Activity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList;
ListView listView;
public static final String TAG_ITEM = "item_name";
ArrayList< String>arrayList; // list of the strings that should appear in ListView
RadioAdapter arrayAdapter; // a middle man to bind ListView and array list 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_view);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // LIST OF STRINGS / DATA THAT SHOULD APPEAR IN LISTVIEW HERE WE HAVE HARD CODED IT WE CAN TAKE THIS INPUT FROM USER AS WELL

        arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add("India");
        arrayList.add("USA");
        arrayList.add("England");
        arrayList.add("Singapur");
        arrayList.add("China");
        arrayList.add("Canada");
        arrayList.add("Srilanka");
        arrayList.add("SouthAfrica");
        Object[] items_2=arrayList.toArray();
      for(int i=0;i<items_2.length;i++)
      { 
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          map.put(TAG_ITEM,(String) items_2[i]);
          itemsList.add(map); 
      }


        arrayAdapter = new RadioAdapter(ListDemo.this,itemsList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And my adapter:

```
       public class RadioAdapter  extends  BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public RadioAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.myTitle); // title
              HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();


        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
      // price2.setText(song.get(HistoryItems.TAG_PRICE2));
        name.setText("Name: "+ song.get(ListDemo.TAG_ITEM));





        return vi;


}
```

I get an error while starting the activity, and this is the stack trace:

```
                  12-16 19:49:46.619: W/dalvikvm(8527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at com.blabla.Dulux.RadioAdapter.getView(RadioAdapter.java:40)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1448)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1184)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.blabla.Dulux-1.apk]
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
         12-16 19:49:46.749: E/AndroidRuntime(8527):    ... 32 more
```

as an afterthought i have also added the class that implements the checkable interface:

```
     public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable{
private CheckedTextView mCheckedTextView;
private final Drawable mCheckDrawable;
private final Drawable mRadioDrawable;
private boolean mIsChecked;

   public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

TypedArray typedArray = null;

// Cache the check box drawable.
typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]       {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple});

if ((typedArray != null) && (typedArray.length() > 0)) {
    mCheckDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
}
    else {
    // Fallback if the target theme doesn't define a check box drawable.
    // Perhaps an application specific drawable should be used instead of null.
    mCheckDrawable = null;
    }

// Careful with resources like this, we don't need any memory leaks.
   typedArray.recycle();

// Cache the radio button drawable.
   typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]      {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle});

    if ((typedArray != null) && (typedArray.length() > 0)) {
    mRadioDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
    }
      else {
    // Fallback if the target theme doesn't define a radio button drawable.
    // Perhaps an application specific drawable should be used instead of null
    mRadioDrawable = null;
}

     // Careful with resources like this, we don't need any memory leaks.
        typedArray.recycle();

       mIsChecked = false;
         }


       /*
       * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
      */
      public boolean isChecked() {
     return mIsChecked;
       }


         /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
        * @see android.view.View#onAttachedToWindow()
     \

      */
       @Override
       protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
       super.onAttachedToWindow();
       mCheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

       // Check if there is a valid GUI element that can visualize the current state.
        if (mCheckedTextView != null) {
         ViewParent p = getParent();
           // Check if the parent of this list item is a ListView
          if (p instanceof ListView) {
          int choiceMode = ((ListView) p).getChoiceMode();
          // Decide which check-state notation to visualize (check box, radio button 
          or  none).
           switch (choiceMode) {
            case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE:
                mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(mCheckDrawable);
                break;

            case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE:
                mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(mRadioDrawable);
                break;

            default:
                mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);
                break;
        }
      }
   }
    }


       /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onFinishInflate()
  */
    @Override
   protected void onFinishInflate() {
super.onFinishInflate();

   }


    /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
 */
   public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
   mIsChecked = checked;

if (mCheckedTextView != null) {
    mCheckedTextView.setChecked(mIsChecked);
      }
   }


      /*
      * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
        */
             public void toggle() {
         setChecked(!mIsChecked);
     }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure `com.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout` is the correct path to where you class is located in your package?

Comment: just changed it myself....i do not think the "exact" path needs to be pasted

Comment: sure it does need to be exact, `com.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout` is not the same as `com.blabla.blabla.CheckableLinearLayout`